# Using listings: "zebra effects" AND line numbers

Tags: listings, color, line-numbering

I just made a code listing with a "zebra effect", just like here: [Creating a zebra effect using listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/creating-a-zebra-effect-using-listings)

But afterwards, the line numbers at the left side of the listing don't appear any more.

This is some of the code that makes the numbers dissapear:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
                            % monospaced font with bold variant

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{keyword}  {blue!100!black!80}
\colorlet{comment}  {green!70!black!100}
\colorlet{STD}        {Yellow}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\usepackage[top     =   2.5 cm,
        bottom  =   2.5 cm, 
        left    =   2.5 cm, 
        right   =   2.5 cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\realnumberstyle[1]{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zebra}[3]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#3}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
    \else
        \color{#2}%
    \fi
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep }%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\lstset
{                                                           %
    language            =   C,                      % the     language of the code
    basicstyle          =   \ttfamily\footnotesize,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    numbers             =left  ,                    % where to put the line-numbers
    numberstyle         =   \tiny\color{black},         % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    stepnumber          =   1,                          % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line 
                                                            % will be numbered
    numbersep           =   25pt,                       % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    backgroundcolor     =   \color{white},              % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
    showspaces          =   false,                      % show spaces adding particular underscores
    showstringspaces    =   false,                      % underline spaces within strings
    showtabs            =   false,                      % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    frame               =   single,                     % adds a frame around the code
    rulecolor           =   \color{black},              % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    tabsize             =   4,                          % sets default tabsize to 4 spaces
    captionpos          =   b,                          % sets the caption-position to bottom
    breaklines          =   true,                       % sets automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace   =   false,                      % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    title               =   \lstname,                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                                                            % also try caption instead of title
    keywordstyle        =   [1]\color{keyword}
                                \bfseries,                  % keyword style
    keywordstyle        =   [2]\color{STD}
                        \bfseries,                  % keyword style
    commentstyle        =   \color{comment},            % comment style
    stringstyle         =   \color{mauve},              % string literal style
    escapeinside        =   {\%*}{*)},                  % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    %morekeywords       =   [1]{*, 
    %                           bla,
    %                           },                      % keywords to the set
    %morekeywords       =   [2]{
    %                           bla,
    %                           },                      % keywords to the set
    %morecomment            =   [l]//,                  % if you want to add comments to the set
    deletekeywords      =   {...}                   % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
}    




\begin{document}

% version with number highlighting "zebra"-style
% this is already part of the first answer
\lstinputlisting[firstline = 0, lastline = 100,numberstyle=\zebra{gray!20}{lightgray!15}{}]{test.txt}

% version without: missing third brackets {}
\lstinputlisting[firstline = 0, lastline = 100,numberstyle=\zebra{gray!20}{lightgray!15}]{test.txt}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you supplement the code with a full (minimal) example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: i've edited it to the code which i'm using to test the listing. the original code and the current solution are in it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to use the package `lstlinebgrd`, this is what you can do with the code borrowed from that answer.

The command `\zebra` takes three arguments. If you use only two as in that answer

```
numberstyle=\zebra{green!35}{yellow!35}
```

you don't get the line numbers printed. To have them you have to give a third empty argument like

```
numberstyle=\zebra{green!35}{yellow!35}{}
```

MWE (partially borrowed from the linked answer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\realnumberstyle[1]{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zebra}[3]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#3}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
    \else
        \color{#2}%
    \fi
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily,numberstyle=\zebra{green!35}{yellow!35}{},numbers=left]
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you don't want to give the third argument, replace the lines

```
\newcommand\realnumberstyle[1]{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zebra}[3]{%
    {\realnumberstyle{#3}}%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
    \else
        \color{#2}%
    \fi
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zebra}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
    \else
        \color{#2}%
    \fi
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

and you will have the line numbers printed only using things like

```
numberstyle=\zebra{green!35}{yellow!35}
```

---

### EDIT

If I was you, I would have a look at the package [`lstlinebgrd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons), but if you still want to use some custom code, the following should meet your settings. Try it.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\zebra}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \lst@basicstyle
    \ifodd\value{lstnumber}%
        \color{#1}%
    \else
        \color{#2}%
    \fi
    \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>9
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}\hspace*{1.14em}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \else
        \rlap{\hspace*{\lst@numbersep}\hspace*{0.6em}%
        \color@block{\linewidth}{\ht\strutbox}{\dp\strutbox}%
        }%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Note that

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for the appreciation. I've added a solution which doesn't require the empty argument.

Comment: Thank you!
It's already better (as there ARE numbers now:), but i've still got two problems:


First, the background color now goes out of my frame.
Second, with a number higher then nine, the background color has got a step.


i just made a pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x58cepcbt23f3it/Syntax.pdf

Comment: @user44467 see the edit.

Comment: very good. now it works fine.

i have a closer look at the named package, too. :)