# forest: How to influence length of edge (make the tree more compact)

Tags: forest

- I use `forest` for the first time and have trouble understanding the (very good) manual.
- I want to make the tree more compact (see annotation).
- Which parameter controls that?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
    forked edges,   
    for tree = {
        align = center, % needed for "\\" in nodes.
        draw,
        font = \tiny,   
        where level = 0{
        }{
          folder,
          grow' = 0,
        },  
    },
 [0
     [1]
     [\ldots]
     [2
        [2.1]
        [2.2]
        [\ldots]
        ]
     [3
        [3.1]
        [3.2]       
        ]
     [4
        [4.1
            [4.1.1]
            [4.1.2]
            [4.1.3]
            [4.1.4]
            [4.1.5]         
            ]   
        [5.1
            [5.1.1]
            [5.1.2]
            [5.1.3]
            [5.1.4]
            [5.1.5]         
            ]       
        ]
 ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Related

- [Have horizontal and vertical tree structure with forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534282)
- [How to build an organization chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342753)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The topmost gap can be shortened using `l=something` on the children of the root (I have set it to 0.6 of the original `l`), but note that as we are shortening the distance, we also need to set `l sep=0` on the root node.

The other gaps are artefacts of using `folder` multiple times on each node. The thing is, in the original code, `folder` resides within two loops, `for tree` and `where level`. That's a bad idea even in general, as it uses more time, but in this tree, the effect is visible as well. I usually suggest `if level` instead of `where level` in these cases, but here, `for tree` followed by `for descendants` seems even more elegant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
  forked edges,
  l sep = 0, for children = {l*= 0.6},
  for tree = {
    align = center, % needed for "\\" in nodes.
    draw,
    font = \tiny,   
  },
  for descendants={
    grow' = 0,
    folder,
  },
  [0
    [1]
    [\ldots]
    [2
      [2.1]
      [2.2]
      [\ldots]
    ]
    [3
      [3.1]
      [3.2]       
    ]
    [4
      [4.1
        [4.1.1]
        [4.1.2]
        [4.1.3]
        [4.1.4]
        [4.1.5]         
      ]   
      [5.1
        [5.1.1]
        [5.1.2]
        [5.1.3]
        [5.1.4]
        [5.1.5]         
      ]       
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: the result of compilation]

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation!

Comment: Is there a way to put 4.1 and 5.1 (which should be named 4.2 :)) side by side so that less vertical space is needed? I can create a new question if that is needed.

Comment: There is: we need to make 4 a `forked edges` (instead of `folder`) node --- which is a bit tricky to achieve, as I don't think it would work if we first made it a folder and then a forked edges node. And I agree, it is more appropriate if this is a new question.

Comment: Ok. I go to bed now and will post a question tomorrow. I will post the link here in the comments. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, this is the follow-up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588083/

Comment: Ahhhh - I feel stupid now. I just now was told by marmot that you are the author of `forest` - I wasn't aware of it! Thanks for taking the time!