# How can I draw this diagram in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

[image]I am new to LaTeX. I would appreaciate your help in drawing the diagram for a beamer presentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: You can find some starting point at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206971/diagram-using-forest-package